# Backing up files before installation of MSI with Visual Studio 2005 MSI/Setup creator automatically

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, windows-installer

I am trying to figure out if there is any way to back up files and registry settings that you are going to overwrite with an MSI that is created in the Visual Studio 2005 msi/setup creator  .  Is it possible to do this without specifying a script that will back up all the files individually which would be time consuming to create and possibly introduce errors/mistakes.

so say I have a file C:\myfile.txt and my installer installs the file to C:\myfile.txt and it already exists it will back it up to c:\mybackup\myfile.txt before overwriting it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. Yet Windows Installer will create a system restore point on each installation. Starting with Vista+, this also includes document files (enabled by default). So in Vista+ you would be able to access previous version of C:\myfile.txt from *Previous Versions* tab of *Properties* dialog.

Installers are not supposed to modify user's documents, therefore no backup is made. And System Restore point is created in Windows XP as well so that you can restore system to the state before installation.

---

During installation Windows Installer automatically creates rollback data. If installation fails, it automatically restores the system to the state before installation started (of course if you don't make system modifications in immediate custom actions).